# Using one pickerView to show different array data

Tags: xcode, uipickerview

I am new to XCode. I was trying to use one pickerView and in that i wanted to show three different array data at different time. Like if i click on the button the picker view shows up with an array of data. Now when I click in background the pickerView goes away. Now I click different button and the same pickerView is populated with different array.
I tried using [pickerView reloadComponent] but don't know how to use it properly.
Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change it's data source. In each of the button's target action set the new data source and reload the pickerview.